# calling a toString() method from a subclass of an abstract class, it throws stackoverflowerror exception

Tags: java

In this code, I have an overridden toString() method. I call this toString() method in a subclass of the ArithBinaryExpression class called AddExpression.
It throws me an exception which goes back to the toString() method. I want to solve this stackoverflow error. Any help is appreciated!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at main$AddExpression.toString(main.java:20)
```

---

```
  public class ArithValue implements ArithExpression {
        private double doubValue;

        ArithValue(double dVal) {
            this.doubValue = dVal;
        }

        public double result() {
            return doubValue;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(doubValue);
        }

    }



public static class AddExpression extends ArithBinaryExpression {
    public AddExpression(ArithExpression leftExp, ArithExpression rightExp) {
        super(leftExp, rightExp);
    }

    public double result() {
        double rightExp = getRightExpression().result();
        double leftExp = getLeftExpression().result();
        return rightExp + leftExp;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Expression: " + "(" + leftExpression.toString() + " + " + rightExpression.toString() + ")";
    }
}
```

---

```
public abstract class ArithBinaryExpression implements ArithExpression {
protected static ArithExpression leftExpression;
protected static ArithExpression rightExpression;

// constructor
public ArithBinaryExpression(ArithExpression left, ArithExpression right) {
    if (left == null) {
        leftExpression = new ArithValue(0);
    }
    else 
    leftExpression = left;

    if (right == null) {
        rightExpression = new ArithValue(0);
    }
    else
    rightExpression = right;


}
// end constructor

// accessors
public ArithExpression getLeftExpression() {
    return leftExpression;
}

public ArithExpression getRightExpression() {
    return rightExpression;
}

}
```

this is the ArithExpression interface:

```
public interface ArithExpression {
    public abstract double result();
}
```

Comment: where you define `leftExpression`?

Comment: It might be a cyclic dependency, which leads to infinite recursive calls which are causing the stackoverflow. `leftExpression` or `rightExpression` might be an instance of `AddExpression`

Comment: I just added in the ArithBinaryClass. That's where its defined

Comment: @Crigges how would I go about fixing the exception?

Comment: Try to add a instanceof check in the toString() method for AddExpression

Comment: what would I test for the instanceof check?

Comment: where is `ArithExpression`? also please share your main method as well.

Comment: if(this instanceof AddExpression)

Comment: I do it for the toString method? or the return statement for the AddExpression?

Comment: perhaps you accidentally instantiated an AddExpressiin with itself as one of its members?

Comment: @PatrickParker where?

Comment: Unrelated but why are your leftExpression and rightExpression static variables?

Comment: Well, it might be what's causing your bug, so maybe not unrelated

Comment: It would have helped if you also pasted the code in main()

Comment: Moved last few comments to an answer because it is definitely something that is likely to silently lead to a disaster. Seeing main() will allow us to find out more

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to let us see what's wrong. PS: a `StackOverflowError` should show more than one line

Answer (score 1):

Conjecture: your bug is manifesting itself due to the fact you're using static variables for leftExpression and rightExpression.

Pasting the main method would allow us to determine if conjecture is true but it seems like something you wouldn't want anyway

Answer (score 0):

Since `leftExpression` or `rightExpression` can be an instance of `AddExpression` you might have a cyclic dependency eg:

```
AddExpression e1 = new AddExpression(null, null);
AddExpression e2 = new AddExpression(e2, null);
e1.leftExpression = e2;
```

or

```
AddExpression e1 = new AddExpression(null, null);
e1.leftExpression = e1;
```

This examples will lead to infinite callbacks and result in the given overflow exception.

Try to add a instanceof check to the `toString()` method of `AddExpression`:

```
public String toString() {
    if(this instanceof AddExpression){
        //print stacktrace or something
        return "possible cyclic dependency";
    }
    return "Expression: " + "(" + leftExpression.toString() + " + " + rightExpression.toString() + ")";
}
```

The check is itself isn't a real solution it is more like a check to ensure that a cyclic dependency is causing the problem. Normally it shouldn't be possible for a calculator (I guess that is what you are trying to code) to create cyclic dependenices. Instead this would cause a Syntax error.

However I can understand that it may be hard to prevent the user from defining any illegal expression, so you might want to count the recursion depth for example by a static variable to prevent at least a stackoverflow.

Comment: When I do the above instance of check, it does not print "possible cyclic dependency" instead throws another StackOverFlowError for the result() method

Comment: but When i perform the same instance of check on the result() method, it prints back the cyclic dependency string

Comment: In that case you have to add the same check for the `result()` method too in `AddExpression`. Please try to understand my examples up there.

Comment: Does that indicate that the result method has a possible cyclic dependency? thats running recursively to cause that stackoverflow

Comment: public double result() {
   double rightExp = getRightExpression().result();
   double leftExp = getLeftExpression().result();
   return rightExp + leftExp;
  }

Comment: i reckon that the in the result() method, when instantiating the rightExp and leftExp, the result() is just recursively called causing the stackoverflow. How would i go on about fixing this?

Comment: I extended my answer, maybe it helps. If not we should discuss this problem in a chat room, since comments are not intended for extended discussions. However you need at least 20 reputation for that. I already upvoted your question to get you closer.

Comment: So how would you use this to get `a+b+c` since you can have an `AddExpression` (a+b) as a left/right expression ?

Comment: As I already wrote the instanceof check isn't a real solution. `a+b+c` is a valid expression and would not result in infinite callbacks. Invalid expressions shouldn't be allowed, and give the user a syntax error. Either use some kind of static recursion depth variable as easy basic fallback mechanism. Or pass a (Identity)`HashMap` of already processed `ArithExpressions` and check if it already contains the current expression, if yes there is a cylic dependency.